# How to install php extension using pecl for specific php version, when several php versions installed in system?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7, php-extension, pecl

I have installed both php5.6 and php7.0 from PPA on Ubuntu according to this manual

http://lornajane.net/posts/2016/php-7-0-and-5-6-on-ubuntu

But I didn't get how to install extensions using `pecl` for php5.6 or php7.0.

For example I have already installed version of `libevent` or `amqp` in php5.6.

Now when I type `pecl install libevent` and my active php version is php7.0 (using `update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0),`pecl`returns message that`libevent` already installed.

But it was installed only for php5.6 (when this version was active) and now I want to do it for php7.0.

Which commands could help me?

**UPD**

I have found this commands for switch pecl to php7.0 and packet them to executable bash scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0

sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set ext_dir /usr/lib/php/20151012/
sudo pecl config-set bin_dir /usr/bin/
sudo pecl config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php7.0
sudo pecl config-set php_suffix 7.0
```

and for php5.6

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6

sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
sudo pecl config-set ext_dir /usr/lib/php/20131226/
sudo pecl config-set bin_dir /usr/bin/
sudo pecl config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php5.6
sudo pecl config-set php_suffix 5.6
```

But they are not help, pecl still gives me `list` of already installed extensions to php5.6, even if I switched to php7.

```
pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package  Version State
amqp     1.7.1   stable
libevent 0.1.0   beta
stats    1.0.3   stable
```

It should be empty for php7.0 !

How to solve the problem?

**UPD**

For amqp I have just installed php-amqp package without using pecl.

```
apt-get install php-amqp
```

And libevent still not exists for php7.
But I hadn't found a way to switch pecl installation between 5.6 and 7 version, so question is still open.

Comment: why you have two version of php?

Comment: I need both for my specific needs. For example, I have 2 projects, one should run with 5.6, second one with 7. And I haven't time to migrate first one to php7.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: ChickenFeet, I think the first answer here is a way to go

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev Matt's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Here's what worked best for me when trying to script this (in case anyone else comes across this like I did):

```
$ pecl -d php_suffix=5.6 install <package>
$ pecl uninstall -r <package>

$ pecl -d php_suffix=7.0 install <package>
$ pecl uninstall -r <package>

$ pecl -d php_suffix=7.1 install <package>
$ pecl uninstall -r <package>
```

The `-d php_suffix=<version>` piece allows you to set config values at run time vs pre-setting them with `pecl config-set`.  The `uninstall -r` bit does not actually uninstall it (from the docs):

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ pecl help uninstall
pecl uninstall [options] [channel/]<package> ...
Uninstalls one or more PEAR packages.  More than one package may be
specified at once.  Prefix with channel name to uninstall from a
channel not in your default channel (pecl.php.net)

Options:
  ...
  -r, --register-only
        do not remove files, only register the packages as not installed
  ...
```

The uninstall line is necessary otherwise installing it will remove any previously installed version, even if it was for a different PHP version (ex: Installing an extension for PHP 7.0 would remove the 5.6 version if the package was still registered as installed).

Comment: Thank you!  This is super useful for Debian 10, where most PHP extensions do not work for any versions < 7.3 using the deb.sury.org pacakges.  That does not work out so well when upgrading old EOL Debian 8 servers, which run PHP 5.6.  Using this method I can build extensions for 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, or 7.2!  ++

Comment: This helped me. `pecl install` kept installing `mcrypt` for unintended PHP version.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! this was very useful for a configuration I'm doing with Ansible and I was needed to use the 7.2 version

Comment: Works wonders when pecl acts up after downgrading the php version through the Laravel Forge controlpanel.

Comment: Hey, I am not so good at messing about in the core Linux file system, what if at some point in the future I wanted to actually remove & purge the php-xdebug ext for the version I am using?

Answer (score 17):

When pecl throws error  is already installed and is the same as the released version

Switch to required php, php-config, phpize versions before installing from pecl

Just run it installation with force flag

```
sudo pecl install -f <package-name>
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. It does, however, appear to remove the previous extension object, which is annoying.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same issue while updating [my Vagrant box with XHGui](https://github.com/Lullabot/trusty32-lamp), as XHGui requires mongodb. I wanted to be able to support profiling on both PHP 5.6 and 7.0.

I dug into the pecl source code, and found that there's a `metadata_dir` config option. That is a path to a directory where the current state of installed packages. Unfortunately, that isn't already namespaced per PHP version. If you try and set it with `pecl config-set`, you get an opaque 'failed' error. It turns out that setting isn't whitelisted as being configuable in the `\PEAR_Config` class:

```
/**
 * Configuration values that can be set for a channel
 *
 * All other configuration values can only have a global value
 * @var array
 * @access private
 */
var $_channelConfigInfo = array(
    'php_dir', 'ext_dir', 'doc_dir', 'bin_dir', 'data_dir', 'cfg_dir',
    'test_dir', 'www_dir', 'php_bin', 'php_prefix', 'php_suffix', 'username',
    'password', 'verbose', 'preferred_state', 'umask', 'preferred_mirror', 'php_ini'
    );
```

In PECL's world, 'global' means it can only be set at install time, and not after.

There's an issue in the PPA tracker over at github: https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/407

The final suggestion there is to build the extension manually for alternate PHP versions. I ended up using pecl for PHP 7 extensions, and manual builds for 5.6. Make sure you run `update-alternatives` for php-config and phpize, and not just php before building:

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config5.6
update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize5.6
```

Then, extract the extension and build it. These steps from the above issue worked for me with the mongodb extension:

`phpize5.6 && ./configure --with-php-config=php-config5.6 && make && sudo make install`

Comment: What can be done, however, is to instruct PECL to 'deregister' the extension so that it can be installed again without removing the existing one. See @Matt Zuba answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get admin permission in Linux Environment-
**Sudo su **
**<>**
Then follow below syntax
**sudo apt-get install php7.3-bcmath**

Here php7.3 (Enter your php version and check by php -v)
bcmath (Enter your extension name)

And if you want to check list of active extensions enter (php -m) in terminal.