# How to install the SQL Server PHP drivers in DDEV-Local?

Tags: php, sql-server, ddev

I'm working on a DDEV-Local project where I need the SQL Server drivers for PHP (`sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv`). How can I add them to its web container? I can't use the extra packages configuration because it requires adding external repositories.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it a bad/irrelevant question? I think it's appropriate for the tags...

Comment: I think it will be a better question if you say in the *question* that this is all about ddev and linux. So it's two questions, 1) How to install the ms sql server drivers on Debian/Ubuntu and 2) How to get those in on ddev. I think you might break the answer into those two parts also.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is updated for ddev v1.14.1+.

Add this `Dockerfile` to `.ddev/web-build`:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
COPY .ddev/web-build/install_sqlsrv.sh /tmp/

# If using DDEV < 1.21.5, use this instead of the above COPY:
#COPY install_sqlsrv.sh /tmp/

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config php-pear
RUN sudo /bin/bash /tmp/install_sqlsrv.sh
```

And save this script as `.ddev/web-build/install_sqlsrv.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script installs MSSQL server. Contains some ddev-specific tweaks:
# - doesn't add ondrej's repo because that's already added
# - doesn't source .bashrc because that will happen anyway.
# - doesn't restart Apache; it's not started at this point.
# - assumes it's being run under sudo anyway and doesn't use sudo or su or exit
# - tries to run apt update as few times as possible
# - Apache's mpm_event module is already disabled.
#   Those don't work well with Docker builds.


# Optional: Exit if already installed.
if php -m | grep sqlsrv; then
  exit
fi

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#step-1-install-php-2
# Some of these packages will be redundant.
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Install sqlsrv drivers.
export PHP_VERSIONS="php7.0 php7.1 php7.2 php7.3"
# Note: Only works for PHP 7.0+.
export PHP_SUFFIXES="7.0 7.1 7.2 7.3"

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
# Download appropriate package for the OS version
OS=$(grep -P '(?<=^ID=)' /etc/os-release | cut -c 4-)
VERSION=$(lsb_release -rs)

sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo chmod 666 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/$OS/$VERSION/prod.list >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

apt-get update
apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https
for v in $PHP_VERSIONS; do
  apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" "$v" "$v"-dev "$v"-xml
done
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >>~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >>~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#step-3-install-the-php-drivers-for-microsoft-sql-server
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419718/how-to-install-php-extension-using-pecl-for-specific-php-version-when-several-p/48352487
for v in $PHP_SUFFIXES; do
  pecl -d php_suffix="$v" install sqlsrv
  pecl -d php_suffix="$v" install pdo_sqlsrv
  # This does not remove the extensions; it just removes the metadata that says
  # the extensions are installed.
  pecl uninstall -r sqlsrv
  pecl uninstall -r pdo_sqlsrv
done
for v in $PHP_SUFFIXES; do
  touch /etc/php/"$v"/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
  touch /etc/php/"$v"/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
  chmod 666 /etc/php/"$v"/mods-available/*sqlsrv*.ini
  printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" >/etc/php/"$v"/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
  printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" >/etc/php/"$v"/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
done
phpenmod sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

# Step 4 skipped because Apache is already configured.
# Step 5 skipped because Apache is not started at this point.

# Reduce image size some.
if [ -f "/.dockerenv" ]; then
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
fi
```

Then just run `ddev start` again.

**Note:** This takes several minutes to build. You can speed it up by removing PHP versions you don't use from the variable at the top of the Bash script.

**Important:** The script must be run with `sudo` to work. If you change the script to add `sudo` to the front of each command, this will break the `apt-get` install lines as `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` no longer will work. You will have to add `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` to each `apt-get` command that requires it. I think the only needed one is

```bash
  sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" "$v" "$v"-dev
```

See the comments in the scripts for where the instructions came from and how they were tweaked to work with ddev.

Comment: That looks like an awful lot of work to accomplish your goal. You can't just get there with `webimage_extra_packages: msodbcsql17` ? I assume you had to add a package source or something?

Comment: @rfay Yes, sources get added. Installing these drivers is a pain every time.

Comment: I updated this for ddev v1.13+, where the script should be added to .ddev/web-build

Comment: Updated 2020-05-13 to make sure pecl is in there and use Debian 10 sources from MS

Comment: It works really well. I updated it to automatically detect the Debian version, which is what the online documentation does.

Comment: Now that `apt-key` is deprecated, I updated with a replacement command.

Comment: Modified to work for non-debian OS, like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is an addendum, or an extension to the 2019 answer by user @wizonesolutions, edited by @rfay.**

For ddev instances that run **Debian 10**, and which should be enabled to **connect to older MSSQL server instances**, there are `Error code 0x2746` problems with TLS (encryption) when the connection from Linux to SQL Server is established.

I need 3 files:

1. `Dockerfile`
2. `install_sqlsrv.sh` shell script
3. custom `openssl.cnf` configuration

The `openssl.cnf` configuration file is necessary to solve the problem described in this blog post: [Installing PDO_SQLSRV on Debian 10](https://tqdev.com/2021-installing-pdo-sqlsrv-debian-10)
:

> Note that Debian requires TLS 1.2 and if your SQL Server does not support that you will run into "Error code 0x2746"...

---

`Dockerfile` - similar to the 2019 file.

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE

ENV NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=v16

RUN curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR && bash install_nvm.sh
RUN echo "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" >>/etc/profile
RUN bash -ic "nvm install $NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION && nvm use $NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION"
RUN chmod -R ugo+w $NVM_DIR

# knb 20210720

COPY openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
COPY install_sqlsrv.sh /var/tmp/
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config php-pear php-dev
RUN /bin/bash /var/tmp/install_sqlsrv.sh
```

---

`install_sqlsrv.sh` shell script - similar to the 2019 script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Install sqlsrv drivers.
export PHP_VERSIONS="php7.0 php7.1 php7.2 php7.3 php7.4 php8.0"
# Note: Only works for PHP 7.0+.
export PHP_SUFFIXES="7.0 7.1 7.2 7.3 7.4 8.0"


if [ ! -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list ]; then
  curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo bash -c "curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list"
fi

sudo apt -y update

for v in $PHP_VERSIONS; do
  sudo apt-get install -y "$v" "$v"-dev "$v"-xml
done

if [ ! -d /opt/microsoft ]; then
  sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt -y install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
  sudo apt -y install unixodbc-dev
  echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >>~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >>~/.bashrc
fi

for v in $PHP_SUFFIXES; do
  sudo pecl -d php_suffix="$v" install sqlsrv
  sudo pecl -d php_suffix="$v" install pdo_sqlsrv
  # This does not remove the extensions; it just removes the metadata that says
  # the extensions are installed.
  sudo pecl uninstall -r sqlsrv
  sudo pecl uninstall -r pdo_sqlsrv
done
for v in $PHP_SUFFIXES; do
  sudo bash -c "printf \"; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n\" >/etc/php/\"$v\"/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini "
  sudo bash -c "printf \"; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n\" >/etc/php/\"$v\"/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini "
  sudo bash -c "chmod 666 /etc/php/"$v"/mods-available/*sqlsrv*.ini"
done
sudo phpenmod sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

---

`openssl.cnf` configuration - line 19 is new, and stuff below line 355 is also new.

I have copied the script from [this Github issue thread](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1112#issuecomment-643522139):

```
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

# Note that you can include other files from the main configuration
# file using the .include directive.
#.include filename

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME            = .

# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file       = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section     = new_oids

# System default
openssl_conf = default_conf

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions        =
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[ new_oids ]

# We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca', 'req' and 'ts'.
# Add a simple OID like this:
# testoid1=1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6

# Policies used by the TSA examples.
tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir     = ./demoCA      # Where everything is kept
certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
#unique_subject = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                    # several certs with same subject.
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts     # default place for new certs.

certificate = $dir/cacert.pem   # The CA certificate
serial      = $dir/serial       # The current serial number
crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    # the current crl number
                    # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl     = $dir/crl.pem      # The current CRL
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key

x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extensions to add to the cert

# Comment out the following two lines for the "traditional"
# (and highly broken) format.
name_opt    = ca_default        # Subject Name options
cert_opt    = ca_default        # Certificate field options

# Extension copying option: use with caution.
# copy_extensions = copy

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crlnumber must also be commented out to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions    = crl_ext

default_days    = 365           # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = default       # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy      = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extensions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options.
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString (PKIX recommendation before 2004)
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings (PKIX recommendation after 2004).
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: ancient versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings.
string_mask = utf8only

# req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = AU
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)

0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName     = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
#organizationalUnitName_default =

commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max          = 64

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_max        = 64

# SET-ex3           = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20

unstructuredName        = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This is required for TSA certificates.
# extendedKeyUsage = critical,timeStamping

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer

basicConstraints = critical,CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Some might want this also
# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ proxy_cert_ext ]
# These extensions should be added when creating a proxy certificate

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This really needs to be in place for it to be a proxy certificate.
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo

####################################################################
[ tsa ]

default_tsa = tsa_config1   # the default TSA section

[ tsa_config1 ]

# These are used by the TSA reply generation only.
dir     = ./demoCA      # TSA root directory
serial      = $dir/tsaserial    # The current serial number (mandatory)
crypto_device   = builtin       # OpenSSL engine to use for signing
signer_cert = $dir/tsacert.pem  # The TSA signing certificate
                    # (optional)
certs       = $dir/cacert.pem   # Certificate chain to include in reply
                    # (optional)
signer_key  = $dir/private/tsakey.pem # The TSA private key (optional)
signer_digest  = sha256         # Signing digest to use. (Optional)
default_policy  = tsa_policy1       # Policy if request did not specify it
                    # (optional)
other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3  # acceptable policies (optional)
digests     = sha1, sha256, sha384, sha512  # Acceptable message digests (mandatory)
accuracy    = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100  # (optional)
clock_precision_digits  = 0 # number of digits after dot. (optional)
ordering        = yes   # Is ordering defined for timestamps?
                # (optional, default: no)
tsa_name        = yes   # Must the TSA name be included in the reply?
                # (optional, default: no)
ess_cert_id_chain   = no    # Must the ESS cert id chain be included?
                # (optional, default: no)
ess_cert_id_alg     = sha1  # algorithm to compute certificate
                # identifier (optional, default: sha1)

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

I recommend to make a "diff" with your existing `openssl.cnf` file.

Do not use this in production. - The openssl.cnf file "dumbs down" the default encryption setting of Debian 10. See the respective Github Issues for details.

Comment: As of DDEV 1.21.5, you have to prefix `ADD` and `COPY` command source locations with `.ddev/web-build/`, as the base path is the project directory now.